# How to refer to a given night

Tags: grammar, idioms, prepositions

How do I succinctly refer to the night between 6th of June and 7th of June?

Comment: The night of the 6th June. That is how the hotel industry does it.

Comment: @ws2 why did you post this as a comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***The night of the 6th June***. That is how the hotel industry does it.